# Why does AWS take a long time to change the password of DB Clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm running this command to change the master user password of a DB Cluster on AWS:

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier development-db \
    --region us-east-2 --master-user-password newpassword --apply-immediately \
    --no-cli-pager > /dev/null
```

When I do this the status of the cluster changes from `available` to `resetting-master-credentials`. Sometimes it'll be in this status for minutes at a time and it just doesn't make any sense to me - I'd expect this change to be near instantaneous.

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't be?

Comment: Without any knowledge of RDS internals: in many cloud products changed settings  are effected by a re-deploy of the product and not by updating the running product. So aws doesn't execute a MySQL native `ALTER USER 'MasterUser' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password'` but  instead starts new rds instances with the new password as an altered boot option and then shifts load to those new instances. That takes more time. But that is an educated guess.

Comment: You'd have to ask AWS that question as it's an implementation detail.